# Apache Camel Quarkus Microservices in Kubernetes using serviceCall()

Tags: kubernetes, apache-camel, quarkus

I have recently read the book "Cloud Native Integration with Apache Camel" (by Guilherme Camposo) and went through the examples. Furthermore, I read the chapter "17.7 Calling clustered services using the Service Call EIP" from "Camel in Action" (by Claus Ibsen).
However, I am failing to understand how 2 separate Camel apps (quarkus/minikube) in the same pod could communicate with each other using the Camel `serviceCall()` method.

I was wondering if there are any good & simple examples which make use of Kubernetes only and don't require a discovery service (such as Consul , Eureka).

Thank you

Comment: So I found that with Camel 3.19 the `serviceCall()` EIP has been deprecated (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17674). I assume that's why there has been no reply on this question.
However, my question still stands: if I have multiple micro services deployed into a Kubernetes cluster which require communicating with each other, what is the best approach to achieve this? 
At the moment my services are using direct HTTP calls e.g.
`.to("http://localhost:8083/graphql/query?bridgeEndpoint=true")` not utilising any discovery service. Thanks